# How to install cm-x86-14.1-r4.x86_64.rpm (it's from Android x86 website and is a flavour of stock android) on Ubuntu 20.04 pc and use it as dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, android, bios

I searched for this problem but couldn't find any information on it. I am a new Linux user so I am not aware with the strong codes used. Kindly provide every detail if you have done it. Find the Android cm os here: https://osdn.net/projects/android-x86/downloads/68670/cm-x86-14.1-r4.i686.rpm/

I have converted the .rpm file to .deb file but can't figure out what do do next, please help me and don't delete my question.

Comment: How did you convert the package-file from .rpm to .deb ?

Answer (score 0):

To install a .deb file, run `sudo dpkg -i file.deb.`

You should probably also read the description on the homepage, and the referred How to Install: https://www.android-x86.org/installhowto.html

On that page I don't see any description on how to install the .rpm file or what it contains. But there are a fine description on downloading and installing from a .iso image.

Comment: That page suggests that it wipes the entire disk. However, the next screenshot lists 'QEMU HARDDISK's to install to, suggesting to me that it can be installed in a virtual machine.